# C++ - Using OpenGL with Code Blocks?

Tags: c++, opengl

Got a predicament with using Code Blocks. I finally have got round to learning OpenGL and I want to use it with OpenGL. I know there is Visual Studio but I like Code Blocks because it is basic and without complexities for me.

Until today. I have absolutely no idea how to get OpenGL to work. Not looking for prize programming at the moment. What I want to achieve is just a black window. The basic of the basics. I have done a good Google search and I can't find an article on installing/activating/utilizing OpenGL.

So what I need is a step-by-step procedure to go from no graphics to a black window. After that, I can at least start playing around to start learning. Can anyone give me a hand? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/

Comment: Have you tried googling for "OpenGL tutorial"?

Comment: I did and I couldn't find any sites useful to my scenario

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, but Code::Blocks has an OpenGL template, which you basically click on, tell the IDE a folder and a project name, click "OK", then click "Build and Run" and you have a window with a black screen and a spinning triangle. Immediate mode for sure, but it's clearly OpenGL. If you want extensions and such, use GLEW, if I remember correctly there's even a wizard for that, too...

Answer (score 1):

I also had some problems recently when I started using OpenGL with C::B.

Download and install SDL from here: http://libsdl.org/. This library can open window, work with keyboard and mouse input, work with TCP/UDP, etc.

To work with opengl, you need GLEW. It have precompiled version only for VS, so you need to build it by yourself. You can get source code here: http://glew.sourceforge.net/.
Then, use these commans to compile it:
1: `gcc -DGLEW_NO_GLU -O2 -Wall -W -Iinclude -DGLEW_BUILD -o src/glew.o -c src/glew.c`
2: `gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libglew32.dll -Wl,--out-implib,lib/libglew32.dll.a -o lib/glew32.dll src/glew.o -L/mingw/lib -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32`
3: `ar cr lib/libglew32.a src/glew.o`
Copy .a files into `MinGW/lib` and headers into `MinGW/include`.

For any project that uses SDL & GLEW & OpenGl, you need to set linker settings:
`Project -> Build options... -> Click on project name in build configurations list -> Linker settings -> Add`.
You need to add these libs in the exact same order:
`mingw32`, `SDL2main`, `SDL2`, `opengl32`, `glew32`, `glu32`.
(You probably need GLU functions. If not, you can omit the last lib.)

Headers to include:
`#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`
`#include <glew.h>`

Because of SDL, your `main()` must always look like `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.

Minimum calls to open a window:
`SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS);`
`SDL_CreateWindow(/*...*/);`
`SDL_GL_CreateContext(/*...*/);`
`glewInit();`
You can find descriptions of SDL functions here: http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryAPI.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. Most of it has been solved but I keep getting this error

c:/program files/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglew32

Comment: Looks like you installed GLEW wrong. You should put `libglew32.a` and `libglew32.dll.a` into `MinGW\lib`.

Comment: I have decided to redo the entire installation as it just isn't working. I have a few questions. Which option on this site do I download? "http://libsdl.org/download-2.0.php". Secondly, the gcc function you speak of didn't work in the Command Line Prompt. Is it meant to be triggered in the file directory? And finally, which SDL files go where?

Comment: `Is it meant to be triggered in the file directory` Yes, of course. `Which option on this site do I download?` This one: http://libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.3-mingw.tar.gz And you should use conents of `i686...` folder, not `x86_64...`.

Comment: Brilliant, downloaded the correct file. Where should I trigger the gcc command then? :). And which SDL files go where?

Comment: Just copy whole contents of `i686...` into MinGW dir. That command should be triggered inside GLEW soucre code dir.

Comment: Huh. I tried the gcc in the root folder and the src folder. Nothing happened. I keep getting the "not recognized" error. Could you post an example filepath so I can check I have it right? As for the i686. I can't find that folder

Comment: `i686` - it's folder (`i686-w64-mingw32`) from this archive: libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.3-mingw.tar.gz . MinGW dir is just MinGW root. For me it contains `bin, include, lib, libexec, ...`.

Comment: I think I have the wrong file. I will download that link you have. In the meantime, I am still having issues with the Command Prompt and gcc

Comment: What issues exactly? Windows can't find `gcc` file? Also, you should execute these commans inside GLEW sources dir from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/1.10.0/glew-1.10.0.zip/download .

Comment: Righty ho, put the i686 in the right folders. As for the gcc, the error is defined as "gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command"

EDIT : Is there supposed to be a gcc file?

Comment: Oh. Looks like you need to set PATH env. variable. How to find it decribed here: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml . PATH is a string. After you find it, you need to add to its end `;` and path of MinGW\bin. For me it's `;C:\MinGW\bin`. When it's done, you can access gcc just with `gcc` command in console.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Same issue

EDIT: Wait. Did you put your GLEW in the MinGW? If so how did you lay it out?

Comment: It still prints `gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command`? About GLEW: you need to find fresh compiled .a files and put them into `MinGW\lib` and put .h headers into `MinGW\include`

Comment: Ok I am really confused. I have tried all ways I know of to make gcc work. Would it possible for you to make a Step-By-Step procedure? That way I may find out where I have gone so wrong

Comment: Oh, ok. Step 1: Download SDL from here: libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.3-mingw.tar.gz. You need to copy all folders from `i686-w64-mingw32` to MinGW dir. If you done it right, you now can compile `int main(int argc, char **argv) {}` program with `SDL2main` and `SDL2` linker settings.

Comment: Works perfectly in a blank environment and a populated environment :). What's next?

Comment: Works in blank environment? It shouldn't. Anyways, next step: You need to modify Path environment variable. Instructions was somewhere above. If you done it right, you will able to run `g++` console command from any folder. If it will print `fatal error: no input files`, then your settings are correct. `g++ is not recognized as an internal or external command` means you did something wrong.

Comment: Something has gone wrong. Same error again What could it possibly be? Where would it have gone wrong?

Comment: Hm, i have no idea. Try to google it. Just to sure. Your path var should now look like `.......;C:\YourPath\MinGW\bin`.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to begin. If you have any idea what to google I appreciate it. I will look. Half the time :)

Comment: I already changed my path variable to the correct value. And it still doesn't work

Comment: If it configured right, you can execute any program inside MinGW\bin from anywhere just by name. Try to put any random .exe inside MinGW\bin and launch it with console from another directory.

Comment: Managed to get it working! It now gives a fatal error :D What's the next step?

Comment: Good. Next step: downloat GLEW source from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/1.10.0/glew-1.10.0.zip/download and extract folder from it anywhere you want. Then, open console in that folder and execute those three commands. If windows can't find `gcc`, use `g++` instead. I'm don't sure, but it will probably work.

Comment: Problem. I can only use the g++ and gcc from inside the MinGW\bin folder. What do I do? The Path variable is already pointing to that folder

Comment: Hm. Try to use full path. Replace `gcc` in these commands with `C:\YourPathHere\MinGW\gcc`. Same thing with `ar`.

Comment: I have managed to get it all working up until the step by step on using the gcc. I have most of the files. But in your instructions you mention .a files in the Include folder. I can't find an of these files in the folder. Was this a typo?

Comment: It's not a typo. After executeing those commands, compiler will create libglew32.a, libglew32.dll.a and glew32.dll in `glew-1.10.1\lib` folder. You should put .a files into `MinGW\lib` and .dll into `MinGW\bin`.

Comment: In that case we have the files in the right types and right place :) What's next?

Comment: It was the final step. Now you might be able to compile projects with `mingw32`, `SDL2main`, `SDL2`, `opengl32`, `glew32`, `glu32` linker settings.

Comment: In that order of linkers?

Comment: Yes, the order is important.

Comment: Got an error upon running. I think there is a file missing

"fatal error: winapifamily.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: Try to replace your GCC with last version from here: http://www.mingw.org/download/installer

Comment: I did that yesterday when I rebuilt MinGW and Code Blocks from scratch

Comment: Right I found what is going on. It's a bug in SDL. It will be fixed in the next version. Moving on, I have the following

#include <glew.h>

It gives the error. Can't find file or directory

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that. You need to find .h headers somewhere in `glew-1.10.1` and copy them into `MinGW\include`.

Comment: Righty ho, we're away! We're now into programming errors.

`SDL_CreateWindow("Tycoon Example",SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,640,480,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);`

Something in that code gives the following error
`error: variable 'SDL_Window window' has initializer but incomplete type`

Comment: Type of the variable must be `SDL_Window *`.

Comment: Changed and now onto a new one

`C:\Users\User\Documents\C++\Tycoon Example\main.cpp|18|||=== Build: Debug in Tycoon Example (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\User\Documents\C++\Tycoon Example\main.cpp||In function 'int SDL_main(int, char**)':|
C:\Users\User\Documents\C++\Tycoon Example\main.cpp|19|warning: unused variable 'glcontext' [-Wunused-variable]|
c:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7)||undefined reference to `WinMain@16'|`

I did a google and can't find anything relevant to my case.

Comment: Here is the rest of the log on the error

`mingw32-g++.exe  -o "bin\Debug\Tycoon Example.exe" obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\map.o   -lSDL2main -lSDL2
c:/program files/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
`

Comment: When you're using SDL, you must use main this way: `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: The main is that way `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: Try to reinstall SDL. If you used version from `i686...` folder, try to install one from `x86_64...` and vice versa.

Comment: I have tried both versions but I am coming across the same. Every SDL function gets the following error. `undefined reference to `SDL_____'` with the ____ relating to the function

Comment: Recheck your linker settings. I have no idea what else can be wrong.

Comment: I think it was Code Blocks. Followed a tutorial for Visual Studio and it worked in only half an hour. I do have issues with it though :P